# Meaningless Spacy Nouns

Tags: python, text, spacy, wordnet

I am using Spacy for extracting nouns from sentences. These sentences are grammatically poor and may contain some spelling mistakes as well.

Here is the code that I am using:

**Code**

```
import spacy
import re

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

sentence= "HANDBRAKE - slow and fast (SFX)"
string= sentence.lower()
cleanString = re.sub('\W+',' ', string )
cleanString=cleanString.replace("_", " ")

doc= nlp(cleanString)

for token in doc:
    if token.pos_=="NOUN":
        print (token.text)
```

**Output:**

```
sfx
```

Similarly for sentence "fast foward2", I get Spacy noun as

```
foward2
```

Which shows that these nouns have some meaningless words like: sfx, foward2, ms, 64x, bit, pwm, r, brailledisplayfastmovement, etc.

I only want to keep phrases that contain sensible single-word nouns like broom, ticker, pool, highway etc.

I have tried Wordnet to filter common nouns between wordnet and spacy but it is a bit strict and filter some sensible nouns as well. For example, it filters nouns like motorbike, whoosh, trolley, metal, suitcase, zip etc

Therefore, I am looking for a solution in which I can filter out most sensible nouns from spacy nouns list that I have obtained.

Comment: Do you want to filter out all words that have spelling mistakes? Did you try a spellchecker approach?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your response. I want to keep nouns that have some meaning. Checking their spellings might be a solution actually of which I never thought about. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well, I tried with `contextualSpellCheck` and it still does not recognize words like `Handbrake`. It does filter out `sfx`.

Comment: Yeah, your are right. I have also tried spellchecker the good part is that it filters out most of the meaningless and misspelled words. So I am half way there. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? It looks more promising.

Comment: Yes I have tried your answer as well. Thankyou so much for your response. It solves half of the problem.

Comment: It actually does the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you can use [`pyenchant` library](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/):

> Enchant is used to check the spelling of words and suggest corrections for words that are miss-spelled. It can use many popular spellchecking packages to perform this task, including ispell, aspell and MySpell. It is quite flexible at handling multiple dictionaries and multiple languages.
>
> More information is available on the Enchant website:
>
> https://abiword.github.io/enchant/

Sample Python code:

```py
import spacy, re
import enchant                        #pip install pyenchant

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

sentence = "For example, it filters nouns like motorbike, whoosh, trolley, metal, suitcase, zip etc"
cleanString = re.sub('[\W_]+',' ', sentence.lower()) # Merging \W and _ into one regex

doc= nlp(cleanString)
for token in doc:
    if token.pos_=="NOUN" and d.check(token.text):
        print (token.text)
# => [example, nouns, motorbike, whoosh, trolley, metal, suitcase, zip]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I think it's promising to the fact that we can do some spell checks. I have tried enchant library but it is still causing some exceptions. For example, it is filtering out some more usable words like cat, mouse, loop, stone, jog, laptop, key, pencil, drum etc.

Comment: @SabaNazir I have just tested against `sentence = "For example, it filters nouns like motorbike, whoosh, trolley, metal, suitcase, zip etc. For example, it is filtering out some more usable words like cat, mouse, loop, stone, jog, laptop, key, pencil, drum etc."` and  got `[example,nouns,motorbike,whoosh,trolley,metal,suitcase,zip,example,words,cat,mouse,loop,stone,jog,laptop,pencil,drum]`. So, it is working for you.

Comment: Actually I think it depends on how the sentences are organised. For a list of words it doesn't work but for a piece of text/sentence it works. Thanks for your responses. Much appreciated.

Comment: @SabaNazir For a list of words, you may still combine several spellcheckers. The approach should work in general.

Answer (score 0):

While using `pyenchant` spellchecker, I have found it useful to do the check after converting the word to uppercase fully. Also Splitting the sentence/phrase and feeding the words one at a time gives better results.

Example:

`enchantChecker.check("landsat".upper())` and `enchantChecker.check("wwii".upper())` returns `True` where as using lowercase words returns `False`.

If you need to mix more than one spellcheckers, another good one is to check `spaCy` library's `is_oov` (out of vocabulary) flag after loading `en_core_web_lg`